# Getting data from select elements without post

Tags: django, post

I have a section of HTML given to me that is essentially three `<select>` elements corresponding to cities, universities and skills which is populated from the back-end.

```
<form action="" method="post">
                            <div class="language-main1">
                                <div class="language1">
                                    <select>
                                        <option>By University</option>
                                        {% for uni in universities %}
                                        <option>{{uni}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="language-main1">
                                <div class="language1">
                                    <select>
                                        <option>By Skill</option>
                                        {% for skill in skills %}
                                        <option>{{skill}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="language-main1">
                                <div class="language1">
                                    <select>
                                        <option>By place</option>
                                        {% for city in cities %}
                                        <option>{{city}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"><p>Clear all filters</p></div>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
                        </form>
```

How can I have it so when the post request is sent I can find the values of the three `<select>` elements?

I have a feeling the answer is to create a form but I've looked into that and it seems quite an undertaking. I was hoping there was an easy way to get past that.

Comment: Aren't you already creating a form?  Django should make it simple to access the results of your post on the server side.

Comment: I meant creating a Django form in `forms.py` and feeding that back.

Comment: Just populate the action attribute of the form to the proper python handler.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects.  I don't see why they handler would necessarily also have to be the same endpoint that generated the form; it doesn't even have to be on the same server.

Comment: The action is being handled by the handler I want it to. I can't access the `<select>` data in the form as I don't think it's being passed through, or if it is I can't find it.

Comment: Well, one thing that comes to mind is the lack of name attributes in any of the form elements.     Is that not how form elements are enumerated?  You might want to build a minimal demo if you've never handled a select before, just so you ensure a working knowledge of how it works.  I'm also seeing none of your option tags have values

Comment: I have indeed added name elements to the `<select>` tags and I can now access them through the POST data.

Comment: Your form tag should have a name, eg `<form name="somename" action="" method="post">`.  Otherwise the option `selected` attribute does not work in Firefox!  Not a problem for you here.. yet.  But trust me, this will come up.  Put a name, always, and you will not have problems.  Thank me later :)

Comment: I respectfully dispute that, @little_birdie, and would like to see an example.

Comment: @DanFarrell I can't reproduce it in jsFiddle, tomorrow I'll try demonstrating it with a regular web page.  But yes, I have seen it several times now, as recently as last week:  A select with a "selected" property yet the dropdown shows the first option, NOT the one with the "selected".  You add a name=  to the form, and it immediately starts working.

Comment: @DanFarrell It has come up for me multiple times however always in a complex application.  I believe now that it may be an interaction with jquery.  I will try to reproduce it in isolation and if I can I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like at the end of the day, the `name` attribute was what was missing from the form.

Answer (score 0):

use forms.ModelChoiceField() for those fields https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield